# Gridview Event Subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have been looking through several posts trying to figure out what I have incorrect in my gridview. I am trying to allow sorting.
I have ensured [EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablesortingandpagingcallbacks?view=netframework-4.8) is set properly

```
EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
```

As well as these

```
AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvEntryPivot_Sorting"
```

And I have this before this element in the page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

My HTML code

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSummary" EventName="Command" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEntry" EventName="Command" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOverdue" EventName="Command" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnInfo" EventName="Command" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" EventName="Command" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="panSummary" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                        <div style="width: 700px; height: 300px; margin: 20px; overflow:auto;">
                            <div class="tb-title">Entry Exceptions Summary</div>
                            <asp:GridView ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ID="gvEntryPivot" CssClass="grid" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvEntryPivot_DataBound" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvEntryPivot_Sorting">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Division" DataField="Division" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="today" DataField="today" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day1" DataField="day1" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day2" DataField="day2" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day3" DataField="day3" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day4" DataField="day4" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day5" DataField="day5" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="day6" DataField="day6" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-CssClass="c2"></asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My event subscription in Page_Init

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            btnSummary.Command += btnTabCommand;
            btnEntry.Command += btnTabCommand;
            btnOverdue.Command += btnTabCommand;
            btnInfo.Command += btnTabCommand;
            gvEntryPivot.Sorting += gvEntryPivot_Sorting;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            messages.Error(ex.Message);
            Logger.Write(MessageType.Exception, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My event code

```
    protected void gvEntryPivot_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = gvEntryPivot.DataSource as DataTable;
        Trace.Warn("event");
        if(dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

            gvEntryPivot.DataSource = dataView;
            gvEntryPivot.DataBind();
            panelGridView.Update();
        }
    }
```

The conversion function

```
    private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch(sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

No matter what I do, the event never triggers - I never get that trace, and there is no postback event. Other buttons and events on the page work just fine. The column headers are not clickable as I would expect a sortable gridview to have.. Am I missing some key setting? Every post I find on this is people having issues after the event fires, not in getting it to fire period.

Comment: Data source table of gridview does NOT persist. You need to show/provide the code as to how you are loading up the grid. (you may well have to save the data source table in viewstate or session - it does NOT persist). If this is a datatable (or dataset), then I would create a dataview - since it has direct sorting built in. So create table, save to dataview, and then save dataview in viewstate or session.

Comment: Also, I don't believe you have to, nor should you specify the on-sorting event in the markup. remove that, and use the property sheet + even builder.